# Handling JWT token in multiple services

Tags: rest, jwt, webapi2

I'm working on a system where it access few rest APIs and we use JWT toke based authentication. Is it possible to use same token across all services ? If yes, how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token can be used (by "used", I mean consumed) across different services as long as they use the same token provider to validate the token.

In fact, token is supposed to be short-lived for security purpose. So in real, you will just use one-time token to establish the user session. And based on the user session, you will do different service handling accordingly.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: hi This worked for me. I used the same key issuer and secret key to generate the token. And It worked for other services also since they use the same credentials. Thank you